# How to use a theme defined variable in res/values/dimens.xml?

Tags: android, xml, themes

Howdy.
In my themes.xml definition, I have the following:

```
<style name="mythemename">
     <item name="d_myvar">100dip</item>
</style>
```

I would like to be able to reference this in res/values/dimens.xml like so:

```
<dimen name="myvar">?d_myvar</dimen>
```

Alas, this doesn't work. When I try to use the **@dimen/myvar** as the height of a LinearLayout, the app crashes with the error "You must supply a layout height attribute."

I have also tried

```
  <dimen name="myvar" value="?d_myvar" />
```

But that won't compile.

How can I define **@dimen/myvar** in my xml so that it loads the **?d_myvar** variable defined in the theme?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your help request on the Italian Startup Scene.

Unfortunately, according to the [syntax of the `dimen` tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen
        name="dimension_name"
        >dimension</dimen>
</resources>
```

you simply can't do it.  In fact, you can reference theme attributes when the syntax specifies:

```
 ?[package:][type:]name
```

**Solutions**:

- [Gix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971749/how-to-use-a-theme-defined-variable-in-res-values-dimens-xml/5971785#5971785) would be the standard way of defining and reusing dimensions.
- Maybe you can reorganize your code to reuse `d_myvar` [through inheritance](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance)?
- As a last and desperate resort, I would go for a shell script that automates the process of variable substitution using xml command line tools.  I have never personally used them, but see for example [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html), [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) or [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipclp/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. My goal was to set the @dimen/myvar once, and have it change based on screen size. My error was thinking this should be achieved with a theme. Instead I've created a values-large directory into which I've placed a new dimen.xml file with values specific for that screen size.

Answer (score 3):

In styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <attr format="dimension" name="exampleDimension"/>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="exampleDimension">100dp</item>
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in your other xml to use the new attribute, you would use it like this

```
android:padding="?attr/exampleDimension"
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the `100dip` part in your dimens.xml like so:

```
<dimen name="myvar">100dp</dimen>
```

then in your theme you can reference it as `@dimen/myvar` if you need, or you can reference it in code using `R.dimen.myvar`

In other words, you don't set the dimension in theme and then reference it in dimens.xml, but you go the other way around. You set the dimension in dimens.xml and then reference that in your theme/style xml.

Comment: It'd be much better for me if I could actually do it the other way around. Is it impossible?

Comment: mrucci explained this in great detail. hope that helps.